# Argument values being corrupted through function calls in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, function, arguments

So I seem to have a sporadic problem, that no amount of Google-fu has thus far been able to solve.  At seemingly random points functions will just break, and after some hunting it appears arguments will begin to get corrupted.

For example

```
Object * testObject = [[Object alloc] init];
NSLog(@"ID: %d", testObject);
[testFunction:testObject];

...

- (void) testFunction:(id)testObject
{
    NSLog(@"ID: %d", testObject);
```

When this happens the Log statements in this case would fail to match up, giving me EXC_BAD_ACCESS warnings or other various issues when I go to use the reference I passed.

Sometimes I can fix the issue by tacking on a 'Dummy value' to the function like so:

```
- (void) testFunction:(id)testObject:(int)dummy
{
```

and then calling it like so:

```
[testFunction:testObject:1111];
```

My function declarations all match in the .h/.m files, the only thing I could guess is that potentially elsewhere in the project there might be missing corresponding function declarations in .h files.  However the functions in question are always done correctly. (I have double, triple checked etc).  I know it's not a retain/release issue, while I am relatively new to Objective-C I have that down pat and I have also ran it through Instruments looking for leaks and there appear to be none.  Any thoughts as to what might cause this, and why issues pop up after changing seemingly completely unrelated code elsewhere in the project?

Comment: Try `%@` instead of `%d` in the NSLog statements.

Comment: The problem is occurring with multiple methods? Have you tried to reproduce this with a test project? Also, it would be best if you'd put real code into your question. The snippets you've posted aren't valid and don't really help anyone diagnose the problem.

Comment: Please dont conflate methods and functions in objective-c, they are very different things.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably that you are logging your objects in the wrong way.
When you log an `Object` you can't just format it like you did.

When you log any code you need to format it precisely right you will get bad access errors.

You should really read up on the apple documentation about the right formats.

And you can do this here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: `%d` is for integer values, not double. Also, it is certainly possible to log an ‘object’ (technically, a pointer) with `%d`, in which case the corresponding memory address is formatted as a decimal integer. Logging a pointer as a decimal integer is always valid regardless of whether the pointer points to a valid object.

Comment: @Bavarious: You are right. I stand corrected. It's all in the apple doc tho:D